# invalid operands using c++ unordered+map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, hashmap

**Problem Statement**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

[image]

**Issue:**

I am trying to implement an algorithm for this problem using a hashmap. This is the first time I am using a hashmap and I am learning about it. I am not sure why I am getting the following error. This problem is from leet code. Thank you in advance.

```
Line 10: Char 35: fatal error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'std::pair<const int, int>')
            if((target - nums[i]) == *umap.find(key))
```

**Code**

```
class Solution {
    public:
        vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
            // key would be the element value would be the complement
            vector<int> sol;
            unordered_map<int,int> umap;
            for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) 
            {
                int key = nums[i];
                if((target - nums[i]) == umap.find(key)) {
                    sol.push_back(i);
                    sol.push_back(umap[i]);
                } else {
                    umap[nums[i]] = i;
                    cout << umap[nums[i]]<< endl;
                }
            }
            return sol;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I know it may seem nitpicky, but can you replace your images of text with actual text? It improves the searchability of the question, helps people who use e-readers, and some image-hosting sites may be blocked (especially at people's workplaces - something that seems unlikely in this time of plague, but still worth considering)

Comment: umap.find() returns an iterator of the unordered map. We can't compare an int with an iterator. Try `(target - nums[i]) == *umap.find(key)`. For more information, look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: @user5876164 We also can't compare an int with a pair.

Comment: @Nick I think your code should contain `*umap.find(key)` instead of  `umap.find(key)` as your compilation result shows...

Comment: @BessieTheCow oops, my bad. Then `umap.find(key)->second` will work fine. Or just use `umap[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` function of `std::unordered_map` returns an iterator to the element found, if an element with the matching key exists. The element that the iterator points to is a `std::pair` containing the key and the value. So if you want to get the value of the element that was found, you need to dereference the iterator and take the `second` value, by doing `umap.find(key)->second`, which is equivalent to `umap[key]` if the element with the matching key exists.